# Placing Blocks on screen part 2

Tags: java, events, mouse

Ok so I posted a question similar to this one already, and asked how I could place blocks on screen whenever I clicked the mouse button. I've already got this working. Which was achieved through the help of some answers as well as making a List and when the mouse button is pressed, a certain tile is added to this list (each tile has an image), and is then repainted. Now since I have multiple tiles in my game, I have obviously made a map of grass tiles. And I have this issue where when I place a block, the event registers but it does not show on the map, but does show on the default screen (Normal JFrame window without anything on it). This will allow for perfect block placement so they do not overlap each other.

My idea was instead of saying when the mouse button is pressed and a block being drawn at the mouse coordinates, I want to find a way to replace the tiles. For example, if I run my game I have a tile map of say 10 x 10 which is filled by a grass tile, when I click on a grass tile, one of the grass tiles will get replaced by a stone tile.

The way I thought of doing this was to do -

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            if(MouseEvent.BUTTON1 == Tile.grassTile.id) {
                tiles.add(new StoneTile(e.getX() - 16, e.getY() - 16,0));

            }

        }
```

The reason why I thought of doing this is because I have assigned all of the tiles an id, and when the e.getX() and e.getY() (Mouse coordinates) have met a tile with a certain id, then execute the code in the above if statement.  Obviously this did not work, but it made sense, and I still think this may work but I most likely missed something. I know for a fact that this isn't the only way and am open to all ideas that are better than mine.

Thank you

Here is runnable program that models my game.

**GameFrame** -

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class GameFrame extends JFrame {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final String TITLE = "Tile Game"; // Game Frame Window Title

    private final JPanel gamePanel;


    public GameFrame(int width, int height) {
        gamePanel = new GamePanel(width, height);
    }


    public void createAndShow() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle(TITLE);
        add(gamePanel);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                GameFrame gameFrame = new GameFrame(640, 480);
                gameFrame.createAndShow();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**GamePanel**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.util.ArrayList
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GamePanel extends JPanel {

private List<stoneTileAdder> tiles; // Stores the Tile objects to be displayed


public GamePanel(int width, int height) {
    tiles = new ArrayList<>();

    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));

    addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            // Do nothing
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
             tiles.add(new StoneTile(e.getX(), e.getY(),0));

             // Repaint the JPanel, calling paint, paintComponent, etc.
             repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            // Do nothing
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            // Do nothing
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g); // Make sure you do this

    // For this example, using black as the color to draw
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);

    // Iterate over the tile list and draw them to the JPanel
    for (stoneTileAdder tile : tiles) {
        Rectangle tileRect = tile.getBounds();
        g.fillRect(tileRect.x, tileRect.y, tileRect.width, tileRect.height);
    }
}
}
```

**StoneTile** -

```
    public class StoneTile extends stoneTileAdder {

    public StoneTile(int x, int y,int id) {
        super(x, y, Tile.TILEWIDTH,Tile.TILEHEIGHT, id);
    }
}
```

**stoneTileAdder** -

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public abstract class stoneTileAdder {

private int x, y, width, height,id;


public stoneTileAdder(int x, int y, int width, int height,int id) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.id = id;
}


public Rectangle getBounds() {
    return new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
}
```

}

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just get the position of the **tile clicked**, rather than the mouse position, then replace it with a stone tile? Also, please give a compilable example. NOT your whole program, just a runnable example that we can fix.

Comment: In your mousePressed method: if (MouseEvent.BUTTON1) { if (mouse position is within a block's bounds) { tiles.add(new StoneTile()); } } or even better, just change the ID of the block that's already there.

Comment: @KylonTyner I like the idea of simply getting the block's bounds, but how would I put that in an if statement. As getting bounds is a Rectangle.

Comment: @CodeLife if your grid is of fixed size, you can simply divide by the grid size (using integer division). So, if your grid is at position (1, 2) and your grid size is 16, the grid's "pixel corners" will be located at (16, 32), (16, 47), (31, 47), and (31, 32). If you click at spot (18, 35) and divide both by 16, you will be left with (1, 2). I hope this makes sense.

Comment: @CodeLife Can you post your Tile class? It's the only way I can solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to add the tiles, would be to find the Component that the mouse presses, like this:

```
@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    Component selectedTile = findComponentAt(e.getPoint());
    if(MouseEvent.BUTTON1 == Tile.grassTile.id && selectedTile instanceof Tile) { 
        tiles.add(new StoneTile(selectedTile.getX(), selectedTile.getY(), 0));
    }
}
```

This gets the coordinates of the tile clicked and places a `StoneTile` exactly over it.

Comment: The '0' refers to the Tile id. May I ask what centerPanel does and what it is? I tested out your code centerPanel is underlined in red. If I give you a runnable example, you will need many of the classes if not all, it simply is not possible to provide one or two classes to run. If that is what you mean, sorry if I misunderstood.

Comment: @CodeLife Hey CodeLife! Thanks for the feedback. `centerPanel` just refers to whatever panel you put your tiles in. It is the parent(the tile is the child). Just change centerPanel to whatever you added the Tiles into. I just realized that that panel name is `tiles` if I'm correct. I have edited my post, so it should work now. You may still need to modify it though.

Comment: @CodeLife (cont.) by runnable example I didn't mean a shortened version of your program, just try to make an example program, which targets your problem. Just make one that adds tiles and is as simple as it can be. For more help, visit: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I have added in a runnable example, I hope it will suffice! Appreciate the help!

Comment: could you please respond?

Comment: Thank you for the response, I tested your code and I get the following error; Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: Game cannot be cast to Tile
 at Game$1.mousePressed(Game.java:78)

Comment: @CodeLife That means there is an error in this line: `Tile selectedTile = (Tile) findComponentAt(e.getPoint());` Try changing it to `Tile selectedTile = findComponentAt(e.getPoint());` I have also edited my post.

Comment: @CodeLife Are you still alive? please accept and/or upvote if this solved your issue